# What is wrong with this example from K&R?

Tags: c

I am trying the listing directories example from K&R section 8.6, but when testing the code it, says "can't access" for every single file in the directory. It is because it's designed for Unix? Below is what I think the code should look like when pieced together, what am I missing? **ADD:How do I fix this code to make it work?**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include "dirent.h"
#include <sys/dir.h>
#define NAME_MAX 14

typedef struct {
  long ino;
  char name[NAME_MAX+1];
} Dirent;

void fsize(char *);

/* print file sizes */
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  if (argc == 1)
    fsize(".");
  else
    while (--argc > 0)
      fsize(*++argv);
  return 0;
}

void dirwalk(char *, void (*fcn)(char *));

/* fsize: print size of file "name" */
void fsize(char *name)
{
  struct stat stbuf;

  if (stat(name, &stbuf) == -1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "fsize: can't access %s\n", name);
    return;
  }
  if ((stbuf.st_mode & S_IFMT) == S_IFDIR)
    dirwalk(name, fsize);
  printf("%81d %s\n", stbuf.st_size, name);
}

#define MAX_PATH 1024

/* dirwalk: apply fn to all files in dir */
void dirwalk(char *dir, void (*fcn)(char *))
{
  char name[MAX_PATH];
  Dirent *dp;
  DIR *dfd;

  if ((dfd = opendir(dir)) == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "dirwalk: can't open %s\n", dir);
    return;
  }

  while ((dp = readdir(dfd)) != NULL) {
    if (strcmp(dp->name, ".") == 0
    || strcmp(dp->name, "..") == 0)
      continue;
    if (strlen(dir)+strlen(dp->name)+2 > sizeof(name))
      fprintf(stderr, "dirwalk: name %s/%s too long\n",
          dir, dp->name);
    else {
      sprintf(name, "%s/%s", dir, dp->name);
      (*fcn)(name);
    }
  }
  closedir(dfd);
}
```

Comment: It's K&R C? That is super old. The current standard is C99. Can you teach yourself from a more up-to-date book?

Comment: What system are you running this on?

Comment: `stat`sets `errno` when it returns -1 ? so what's the value of `errno` ?

Comment: @Michael: K&R is still considered a must-have reference by most C programmers.

Comment: What system and what directory?

Comment: are you sure you have the read permission on that dir?

Comment: There's a newer version of the K&R book which is up to date with C89. I'm seeing a function prototype in there so that must be the one he's using.

Comment: @Jakub: I am running this on ubuntu 11

Comment: @David: I tried it on a new directory with sample files in it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The structure `Dirent` defined in your example probably doesn't match `struct dirent` for your system (it doesn't on mine).

On a Linux system the following will fix the problem:

```
/* dirwalk: apply fn to all files in dir */
void dirwalk(char *dir, void (*fcn)(char *))
{
    char name[MAX_PATH];
    struct dirent *dp;

    DIR *dfd;

    if ((dfd = opendir(dir)) == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "dirwalk: can't open %s\n", dir);
            return;
    }

    while ((dp = readdir(dfd)) != NULL) {
            if (strcmp(dp->d_name, ".") == 0
                            || strcmp(dp->d_name, "..") == 0)
                    continue;
            if (strlen(dir)+strlen(dp->d_name)+2 > sizeof(name))
                    fprintf(stderr, "dirwalk: name %s/%s too long\n",
                                    dir, dp->d_name);
            else {
                    sprintf(name, "%s/%s", dir, dp->d_name);
                    (*fcn)(name);
            }
    }
    closedir(dfd);
}
```

The `readdir` function is system-specific, so you should consult the documentation for yours. On a Linux system you can type `man 2 readdir` in a terminal to see the online manual for the `readdir` function.

Comment: It's complaining no member name is found. Do you know what I should replace name with?

Comment: It's fixed in the code above. The correct member name is `d_name`.

Comment: Do you know how to fix this error? :format ‘%81d’ expects type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘__off_t'. It's complaining about printf("%81d %s\n", stbuf.st_size, name); from fsize.

Comment: Try `printf("%81lu %s\n", stbuf.st_size, name);`. `off_t` is probably an unsigned type.

Answer (score 7):

Where to start....

1. NAME_MAX and PATH_MAX actually exist... you shouldn't define these yourself.
2. Dirent actually exists ([struct dirent](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/dirent.h.html) from [dirent.h](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/dirent.h.html)), so use the existing `struct dirent`.
3. You aren't using braces consistently (always use braces), making your code unreadable.
4. You should be including <dirent.h>, not "dirent.h" (unless you have a specific reason to do so).
5. You need to forward-declare your functions before you use them.

Also, in the future, it would be helpful to know:

1. Your compiler.
2. Your operating system.
3. The errors emitted by your compiler.

As the above can make it much easier to resolve your issues. More importantly, though, you mentioned that you are learning "K&R C". Note that "K&R C" predates the standardization of the C programming language by the International Standards Organization (ISO). Since K&R C, there have been several iterations of ISO C: ISO C 1989 (a.k.a. C89), ISO C 1990 (a.k.a. C90), and ISO C 1999 (a.k.a. C99). I strongly suggest you teach yourself from a more up-to-date book.

Also, if you are targetting UNIX, I strongly recommend you get comfortable with the UNIX Manual Pages. The [UNIX Manual Pages chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fngkomobalnoppphmglonpdgoonpdafh) makes it really easy to access the [official IEEE Std. 1003.1 POSIX manual pages](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/). I strongly suggest you look at those to understand what standard functions are available, what is expected of the inputs, what is guaranteed of the outputs, and how they may fail.

Comment: Great answer +1, just one little thing though.
I strongly suggest that he sticks with K&R book, and read more about modern standards, because the book in itself is, IMO, the greatest book ever to teach C.

Comment: @Mark: Start by dropping your `Dirent` in favor of the system's `struct dirent`, then add `-Wall -Werror` to your compiler flags.

Comment: "You need to forward-declare your functions before you use them." I don't understand this part, do you mean I should place all my forward declaration at the top?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken this is sample code from "The C Programming Language." While I agree with your assessment, commenting on Dennis Ritchie's coding style is akin to telling the Pope he is wearing a dress. +1

Comment: @Mike Steinert, the Pope is both human and fallible. Dennis Ritchie is indeed quite brilliant, but that doesn't mean his coding style is above reproach.

Comment: Ah, perhaps the Pope was a bad example. At any rate I suspect most s/C-programmers/Catholics/ would cut s/Dennis Ritchie/The Pope/ some slack in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Your specific problem is your homebrew `Dirent`. [`readdir`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/readdir.html) actually returns a `struct dirent *` and its layout does not necessarily match your `Dirent`, in particular there are probably more members before the `d_name`. So, when you look at your `dp->name` to get the name you probably end up trying to read some non-string as a string and that gives you nonsense; everything falls apart once you get nonsense.

So fix up everything that Michael Aaron Safyan mentioned, turn up your compiler's warning flags (`-Wall -Werror` is a good starting place for gcc), and your program should start working.

Comment: All I have to do is fix those warnings?

Comment: I have dropped dirent, but it complains no member name is found.

Comment: @Mark: The member is `d_name` in the real `struct dirent`. Then fix all the warnings. Have a look at this: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/dirent.h.html

Answer (score 2):

The problem is obvious when you look at the compiler warnings. At least on my system GCC gives:

```
x.c: In function ‘dirwalk’:
x.c:58:16: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type
```

This is the `while ((dp = readdir(dfd)) != NULL) {` line. As Michael has pointed out, `struct dirent` already exists and this is what is returned by `readdir`. You are using a custom, incompatible structure, this causes you to get garbage instead of file/dir names.

The quickest fix to make it work is to get rid of `Dirent` and use `struct dirent` instead.